# Changing icon size in Applescript "choose file" window?

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to change the icon size in a "choose file" preview window? I'd like to make my preview thumbnails larger.

Here's the code I'm using. Pretty basic:

```
    set theFile to (choose file of screenFolder with prompt "Select a file to read:" of type {"JPG"})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't change the size of the preview window (I apologize for any inconvenience).

### Note

Your code won't compile. I'm assuming you want `screenFolder` to automatically be opened. If that is true, then use the `default location` property, which automatically navigates to the desired folder. Your new code should look something like this...

```
set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select an image to read:" default location screenFolder of type {"JPG"})
```